# Not able to access right node_modules path on webpack-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am trying for the first time to work with angularjs with rails as the back end. I am using **webpack-rails** gem for the webpack configuration for managing css and other style sheets.

First I made a sample angular + rails app to display a simple text "Hello world". By default the font was in times new roman. Then I added bootstrap to the **package.json** file as follows.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "shine",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "stats-webpack-plugin": "^0.4.3",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7"
  }
}
```

Then I ran `npm install` which generated a folder named **node_modules**
with all the packages mentioned in the `package.json` in `Project/node_modules` path.

And webpack configuration to access access these package files is given in the

**webpack.config.js**

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var StatsPlugin = require('stats-webpack-plugin');

// must match config.webpack.dev_server.port
var devServerPort = 3808;

// set NODE_ENV=production on the environment to add asset fingerprints
var production = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

var config = {
  entry: {
    // Sources are expected to live in $app_root/webpack
    'application': './webpack/application.js'
  },

  output: {
    // Build assets directly in to public/webpack/, let webpack know
    // that all webpacked assets start with webpack/

    // must match config.webpack.output_dir
    path: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'webpack'),
    publicPath: '/webpack/',

    filename: production ? '[name]-[chunkhash].js' : '[name].js'
  },

  resolve: {
    root: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'webpack')
  },

  plugins: [
    // must match config.webpack.manifest_filename
    new StatsPlugin('manifest.json', {
      // We only need assetsByChunkName
      chunkModules: false,
      source: false,
      chunks: false,
      modules: false,
      assets: true
    })]
};

if (production) {
  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compressor: { warnings: false },
      sourceMap: false
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': { NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production') }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin()
  );
} else {
  config.devServer = {
    port: devServerPort,
    headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }
  };
  config.output.publicPath = '//localhost:' + devServerPort + '/webpack/';
  // Source maps
  config.devtool = 'cheap-module-eval-source-map';
}

module.exports = config;
```

And in my **webpack/application.js** I am calling that bootstrap package as follows.

```
require("bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css");
console.log("Hello world!");
```

Now when I restart the server and reload the page I don't see any change in the font instead in the console I am getting.

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
    at webpackMissingModule
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps...

```
require('boostrap');
```

if that doesn't work, check to see if the file `bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css` exists

Comment: I just added `require('bootstrap')` like you said. Now I dont see console errors. But I dont see any change in font either. And yes the file does exists in **bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css**. I dont know why its not fetching that.

Comment: require brings it into your file for use, but you haven't actually configured webpack to utilize bootstrap.css - you'll have to look up how to configure webpack to utilize a package.json CSS file.

Comment: I have gone through the `wbpack-rails` documentation. I don't see any steps to do what you are asking me to do. Could you please tell me how can I do that ?